# Generate WSDL with a complex subtype using Laminas SOAP in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap, wsdl, laminas

i'm trying to figure how to generate multilevel wsdl using Laminas SOAP in my Laravel.. i did read the documentation and chatgpt too.. but im still confused how to set up, here's the link :
https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-soap/auto-discovery/

This is my controller code :

```
public function soap()
{
    $server = new Server(
        route('soap-wsdl'),
        [
            'actor' => route('soap-server'),
        ]
    );

    $this->populateServer($server);
    $server->setReturnResponse(true);

    $response = response($server->handle());
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    return $response;
}

public function wsdl(Request $request)
{
    $wsdl = new AutoDiscover();

    $this->populateServer($wsdl);
    $wsdl->setUri(route('soap-server'))
        ->setServiceName('InaportWSDL');

    return response()->make($wsdl->toXml())
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
}

private function populateServer($server)
{
    // Expose a class and its methods:
    $server->setClass(ResponseServices::class);
}
```

and this is my ResponseServices class (or Controller) :

```
class ResponseServices {
/**
 * @param string $user
 * @param string $password
 * @param array $detail
 */
public function entryRpkro($user, $password, $detail)
{
}

}
```

result using wizdler :

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <entryRpkro xmlns="http://localhost:8000/soap">
        <user>[string]</user>
        <password>[string]</password>
        <detail>[Array]</detail>
    </entryRpkro>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

So i want to change this wsdl into this :

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <entryRpkro xmlns="http://localhost:8000/soap">
        <user>[string]</user>
        <password>[string]</password>
        <detail>
          <name>[string]</name>
          <age>[int]</age>
        </detail>
    </entryRpkro>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: How would you describe _"multilevel wsdl"_ in one sentence your own? _What_ do you want to set up and what is preventing yourself from doing it? This is not a trick question or similar, but if you share more of your current understanding in your own words - even incomplete or wrong - will help you to obtain better feedback if not already an answer to your question.

Comment: And just a remark, basically from the docs you link: `@param array $detail` - (Laminas) _"WSDL autodiscovery utilizes PHP docblocks provided by the developer to determine the parameter and return types. In fact, for scalar types, this is the only way to determine the parameter types, and for return types, this is the only way to determine them. This means that providing correct and fully detailed docblocks is not only best practice, but required for autodiscovery."_ - Perhaps the clarification question would be: _"Why do you use `@param array $detail` when you don't want an array as detail?"_

Comment: @hakre Sorry for not using the right question, but the point is, i just want to generate like the last code i gave

Comment: Yes, sure, that I've read, but wanting something is not a good form to ask a programming question on Stack Overflow because it does not say much about why you think this should be possible. Have you tried declaring your own type for the property $details instead of using the generic array?

Comment: i did, nothing work.. even delete that line

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Create another file `Details.php`. Don't forget to set the namespace.

```
class Details
{
    /** @var string */
    public string $name = '';
    /** @var int */
    public string $age = '';
}
```

Change the above code to something like this:

```
class ResponseServices {
    /**
     * @param string $user
     * @param string $password
     * @param \FULL\NAMESPACE\PATH\Details $details
     */
    public function entryRpkro(string $user, string $password, Details $details)
    {
        // Now you can access $details->name or $details->age
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you always need to use FQCN in the `@param` and `@return` Annotation in order to get the correct mapping with laminas.
Maybe in the future you also want to adjust the [complexTypeStrategy from laminas](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-soap/wsdl/#adding-complex-type-information). So far `ArrayOfTypeComplex` has always worked best for me.